# Accessing google sheets via the PHP API on a G-Suite account

Tags: php, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I am a member of the organization and I set up a new project, enabled google sheets API and set up a service account with owner role, I downloaded the json file containing the credentials, including the cert and all that.

I went in and shared this sheet with the email generated for that service account.

When I run the PHP script and I call getSpreadsheetFeed(), the sheet does not show up at all.

When I take this same sheet and put it on my own personal google drive and share it with the same service account, it shows up as expected.

This sheet is in a "Shared Drive" folder.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');

$client = new Google_Client;
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$client->setApplicationName("MSE Reader Application");
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);

if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}

$accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion()["access_token"];
ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance(
    new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken)
);

$spreadsheets = (new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService)->getSpreadsheetFeed();

print_r($spreadsheets);

?>
```

Comment: Couple of things, you should check if the file in question is set so that it can be shared outside of your domain. Second is to check if the service account has permission to access the folder where the Sheet is, if it can't view all the files, then `getSpreadsheetFeed()` won't work. Lastly, make sure you followed all the steps in [the quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) although since your code has worked before I doubt this is the issue.

Comment: Same experience here. Unable to get this gSUite (shared drive) spreadsheet listed via getSpreadsheetFeed

Comment: "The sheet does not show up at all" - that sounds strange. What do you mean by that? What have you tried to debug the script?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve this using the official client as https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client seems to be outdated and is not actively maintained.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php

This quickstart works for me:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

// Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
// https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
$spreadsheetId = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms';
$range = 'Class Data!A2:E';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
```